# Check if a given rectangle can be drawn on cylinder side surface.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I've been solving programming challenges and got stuck with this not really programming one.

> Check if a rectangle $a\times b$, $(a \le b)$ can be drawn on a side-surface of a cylinder with height $H$ and circumference $L$.

You can also think of this problem as winding a rectangle around a cylinder.

Of course, there is an easy case when it is sufficient to check that $L\times H$ rectangle fists $a \times b$ one. This can be done as described in this [article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2691523?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

I assumed that it would be optimal for a rectangle to be wound leaving no space between its 'layers', see a picture.
[image]

I.e. rectangle 'layers' are stacked on top of each other. 
Having assumed this, I can now fix the angle formed by the rectangle and the horizontal line. Knowing this, I asked what height do I need to fit a rectangle $a \times b$ that forms angle $\theta$ with horizontal line into another rectangle with infinite width. Note, I fixed smallest possible $\theta$ (layers stacked) so that that height is minimal.

I did this by looking at the following picture 
[image]

To do this, I found $$\sin \alpha = \frac{a}{L}$$. Now I could compute $h$. $$\sin \alpha = \frac{a}{L} = \frac{h}{b}$$ and $$h = \frac{ab}{L}$$. So, the height needed to fit the rectangle is this $h$ plus the height of the rectangle at the bottom (below lenngth-$L$ segment). The height needed to fit this rectangle equals to $$\frac{a\sqrt{(L^2 - a^2)}}{L}$$, which is just height of a right triangle found by using area formulae.

Now, I found the height of an infinite-width rectangle I was looking for. It's time to come back to original problem and compare cylinder height with the height I got.

The rectangle $a \times b$ can be fit on a side-surface of a cylinder with height $H$ and circumference $L$ if the following inequality holds:

$$\frac{ab}{L} + \frac{a \sqrt{L^2 - a^2}}{L} \le H$$ .

Also, it is impossible if $a > L$ or if $a = L$ and $b < H$.

Apparently, there is something wrong with this appoach. Could you help me please?

Problem source: NEERC 2012-2013, Eastern subregional, Problem J. 
http://acm.urfu.ru/qf/2012/qf_12_eng.pdf

http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1919&locale=en

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your approach when applied to the problem of cutting a very long narrow rectangle from a cylinder ($a \ll b$). When the piece to be cut out is square, however, as in the example data given at the end of the problem, I think this "wrapping" solution is not optimal. To cut out a square, I think it is always optimal to put one edge of the square flush against the bottom edge of the cylinder.

Comment: Hmm, indeed, thanks! I solved the problem by first checking the sufficient condition of fitting one rectangle into other from the article and then, if the condition fails proceeded with "wrapping".